# Spam mail from own mailserver, but there is no outgoing mail in postfix log?

Tags: spam, email-spoofing, postfix

Today I received a phishing mail from my own (valid) sender address (info@example.com).

I checked the e-mail header and see the mail was received by my valid mailserver.

```
Received: from mail.example.com ([::1]:36128) by domain.1blu.de (kopano-dagent)  with LMTP; Mon, 14 Nov 2022 04:45:45 +0100
```

SPF, DMARC and DKIM are not valid. There is no outgoing mail in my postfix log.
How the spammer can send these emails?

Comment: Any header in an e-mail can be spoofed, including a `Received` one. The only rule is that it is not possible to spoof all of them...

Comment: The question title and body do not match. The email was not sent from your server. These were sent from an outside party. What you want to know is how you received it even though SPF, DKIM, and DMARC failed?

Comment: `[::1]` is not your mailserver.  This spammer isn't even competent at forging MIME headers.

Comment: @BenVoigt I fail to see your point. `[::1]` is IPv6 localhost, that `Received`header could be valid

Comment: @Ángel: But then it would be "from (some alias of domain.1blu.de)".  I didn't say `[::1]` cannot be *a* mailserver, I said it is not an address for OP's mailserver.

Comment: If it's localhost, it is their server. I don't know why it woul use a HELO of `mail.example.com` (which is likely anonymized and could actually be an obscure alias of the server)